# F# Partial Active Pattern Matching "Rule Will Never Be Matched"

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, active-pattern

Given the following active pattern:

```
let (| HasMatch |) (x:string) = 
  if x.Contains("0") then Some()
  else None;;
```

And the following pattern matching func:

```
let testFn x = function
  | HasMatch i -> printfn "%A" i
  | _ -> printf "nope";;
```

The last line's wildcard pattern says `warning FS0026: This rule will never be matched`

All of the examples i see seem to infer that partial active patterns must return `Some('a)` to match, and that ones that return `None` get captured by the wildcard. The error seems to say differently.

What am i missing?

Comment: Your describing a partial active pattern, but your trying to define it with a single case one.  There are some pretty good tutorials here:  http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2010/07/f-pattern-matching-for-beginners-part-6-active-patterns.html  The summary at the bottom describes the different types that are detailed in the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should add the `None` case to the active pattern declaration as follows:

```
let (| HasMatch | _ |) (x:string) = 
  if x.Contains("0") then Some()
  else None;;
```

In your orignal example, the compiler infers that you actually want to return the `Option` type.  When you run the `printf` in your example, you would see it print `Some Null` when there is a match.

Also, it is bad to return `Some()`, you should return say `Some(x)` or similar

Comment: yep, def forgot the `| _ |`